# How to expose enum to QML from non QObject in C++ (Qt 6)

Tags: c++, enums, qml, qt6

I want to expose an enum to QML from C++ without creating a QObject but it's not working for me. Any ideas?

For comparison, I've included minimal code exposing an enum to QML using `Q_ENUM()` from a QObject that contains `Q_OBJECT` and `QML_ELEMENT`.

I have tried using a class that contains `Q_GADGET` and uses `Q_ENUM()`. I have also tried using a namespace with `Q_NAMESPACE()` and `Q_ENUM_NS()`. In both cases the enum doesn't get recognised by QML.

**Full QObject QML_ELEMENT example**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>

class MyFullQObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QML_ELEMENT
public:
  using QObject::QObject;

  enum MyEnum {
    First,
    Second,
    Third
  };
  Q_ENUM(MyEnum)
};
```

**Q_GADGET example**

```
#include <QtQml>

class MyGadget {
  Q_GADGET
public:
  enum MyEnum {
    First,
    Second,
    Third
  };
  Q_ENUM(MyEnum)
};
```

**Q_NAMESPACE example**

```
#include <QObject>

namespace MyNamespace {

Q_NAMESPACE

enum MyEnum {
  First,
  Second,
  Third
};
Q_ENUM_NS(MyEnum)

}
```

**Usage in QML**

```
import QtQuick
import MyModule

Item {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("MyFullQObject enum: " + MyFullQObject.First)
    console.log("MyGadget enum: " + MyGadget.First)
    console.log("MyNamespace enum: " + MyNamespace.First)
  }
}
```

In QML, the first console line will work. The second one generates an error "ReferenceError: MyGadget is not defined". Likewise for the third one (if the second one is commented out to allow the program to continue).

Within CMake, both classes and the namespace are included in the same CMake module and I link the generated MyModuleLibplugin to the executable, which successfully makes it available for QML `import`.

Comment: Actually `Q_GADGET` should be enough. Did you register the class? See [this](https://qml.guide/enums-in-qt-qml/) tutorial for the example.

Comment: Actually I have read that tutorial before. My understanding is that as of Qt 6.2, you don't need to manually register classes. I have other QML_ELEMENTs and Q_GADGETs in my app that become part of the moc. However when I look at the generated files the enum only appears in the ones that are QML_ELEMENTs. I'm wondering if it's a bug??

Comment: I am in conversation with Qt engineers and will post an answer when I'm clear on it. There are solutions that will work just using macros (no need for manual registration in main.cpp). For reference see [Qt bug report 114394](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-114394)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution that uses only macros without needing to manually register anything in main.cpp.

Normally you would use `QML_ELEMENT` with `Q_OBJECT` as in `MyFullQObject` to cause a QObject to be made available to QML.

However this same macro can be used with `Q_GADGET` or `Q_NAMESPACE` and this results in their enums becoming available in QML.

--

As a side note for curiosity, while it now becomes possible to put the following in QML (without error and with normal component highlighting in Qt Creator):

```
 MyGadget { id: myGadget
    Component.onCompleted: console.log('Made a MyGadget')
 }

 MyNamespace { id: myNamespace
    Component.onCompleted: console.log('Made a MyNamespace')
 }
```

it would generate the runtime error "Element is not creatable", as you would expect.

Comment: Hi, Paul. Are you sure that you don't need to explicitly register the type with this approach? What would be the import command in QML?  
Official docs (for Qt6.6) state that registration is still should be done.

Comment: Q: Are you sure that you don't need to explicitly register the type with this approach? A: Yes I'm sure. With Qt 6.2+ and CMake, using the macros (`QML_ELEMENT`, `Q_GADGET`, etc.) is enough, alongside `qt_add_qml_module`.
Q: What would be the import command in QML? A: Use the URI of the QML module. e.g. `qt_add_qml_module(SprinkleLib URI Sprinkle VERSION 1.0 ...)` -> `import Sprinkle`.

Comment: Q: Official docs (for Qt6.6) state that registration is still should be done. A: The documentation remains poor unfortunately and rather disjointed. Yes registration is needed, but yes it is done automatically.
See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-qml-module.html#auto-generating-qmldir-and-typeinfo-files "The backing target's C++ sources are scanned at build time to generate a typeinfo file and a C++ file to register the associated types."
Short answer: try it and you'll see it works. I have a published app by this approach.

Comment: NB: For that `SprinkleLib` example, the QML module that gets generated is `SprinkleLibplugin` and this is what you need to link to your QML target that needs to use the import. e.g. `qt_add_executable(AppTarget main.cpp) qt_add_qml_module(AppTarget ... QML_FILES Main.qml ...) target_link_libraries(AppTarget PRIVATE Qt6::Quick ... SprinkleLibplugin)`

Comment: Oh, I see. Explicit registration is "kind of" of still required but could be automated via CMake. Too bad I'm building a MSBuild solution so this option is not available. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for me that work with forced registration only:

***.h**:

```cpp
class TestClass
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    TestClass();

    enum class Test
    {
        VALUE1,
        VALUE2,
        VALUE3,
    };

    Q_ENUM(Test)
};
```

**main.cpp**:

```cpp
qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject(TestClass::staticMetaObject, "MyClasses", 1, 0, "TestClass", "Error: Cannot create instance");
```

**QML**:

```js
import MyClasses 1.0

Window {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(TestClass.Test.VALUE3)
    }
}
```

`TestClass.VALUE3` works too.

Tested with **Qt 6.4.3**